# rails search all columns of all rows for value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search record that stores an all_words column. It is a list of words separated by a space. I have another model named Lead. I want to search all the columns of all the rows of the leads table for the values in all_words. And any record that produces a match in any of its columns will be retrieved. Kind of like this:

```
possible_values = search.all_words.split
Lead.where(first_name: possible_values )
.where(last_name: possible_values )
.where(status: possible_values )
...
```

But this doesn't look clean. How can I go about this?

Comment: Unless you do it just for fun you shouldn't use DB for such search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Indexing**

You'll be much better suited to using an index-based search solution

I wrote about this the other day - if you're going to "search" your database (especially multiple attributes), you really need to use a third party solution to provide access to the data you require.

The "common" way to search databases, across all flavours of SQL, is to use [`full text search`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search) (which basically looks up information within an array of different attributes / columns, rather than specific matches).

The following solutions are popular for Rails based projects:

> - [Thinking Sphinx](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/)
> - [Sunspot Solr](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot)
> - [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

--

**References**

The magic of these is that they will *index* any of the data you wish to search, storing the data in a semi-persistent data set.

This is vitally important, as one of the main reasons why full text searching your database is a *bad* idea is the performance implications it will cause. You'll be best using one of the aforementioned gems to get it working correctly

There's a [good Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot) about this here:

[image]

Comment: I already have a gem on my system called ransack. Does that have full text search capability like these other ones?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is full-text search. Depending on the type of database you have you will use different strategies.

You will be able to create a search index on as many columns as you like.

**For Postgresql**

The good thing is that Postgresql already has full-text search capabilities. You can use those gems to benefit from it.

[PG Search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search)

[Textacular](https://github.com/textacular/textacular)

**For Mysql**

[Dusen](https://github.com/makandra/dusen) (uses FULLTEXT index capabilities in MySQL and LIKE queries)

[Thinking sphinx](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/) (uses Sphinx search server)

[Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) (uses solr search server)

Comment: Sunspot Solr at https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot is a mostly just-works full-text search solution

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code which i tried for searching a key-value in all columns of all tables. However this answer may not be the exact thing being asked here.
I think this code will work for postgres, on rails console and the program searches for string type columns.

```
    # Define the value to search for
search_value = 'keyValue'

# Get all table names
table_names = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables

# Iterate over the table names
table_names.each do |table_name|
  # Get the column names for the current table
  puts "#{table_name}"
  columns = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns(table_name)

  # Build a dynamic postgreSQL query for each column
  columns.each do |col|
    if col.type == :string  
        begin
            query = "SELECT * FROM #{table_name} WHERE #{col.name} LIKE '#{search_value}';"
            # Execute the query
            results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
            # Print the results if any matches are found
            if results.any?
                puts ""
                puts "********************************"
                puts "Table: #{table_name}"
                puts "Column: #{col.name}"
                results.each do |row|
                    puts "Row: #{row.inspect}"
                end
                puts "********************************"
                puts ""
            end
        rescue
            puts "#{col.name} checking failed"
        end
    end
  end
end
```